# Crawler with Web Scrapy - error selecting Tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm following [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/making-web-crawlers-scrapy-python) tutorial to Crawler using the Scrapy Web Library on this [site](https://g1.globo.com/). Considering the image below, I need to collect the text inside the span tag ("Mãe cria sozinha ...")

[image]

Using the scrapy shell, I'm trying to use `response.css` to collect, but I'm returning an empty list:

```
response.css("a._b >span::text").extract()
```

I believe I am wrong in passing the tags, so what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I **strongly recommend** reading this article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the source of the `URL` using ctrl/cmd + U, you will be unable to find class`_b`and thus your response is returned empty are not getting your desired results. Moreover `bstn-hl-title` class is also not available in the source of the webpage as well. Thus all fields of item will empty as well. In scrapy you have access to the source that you see in the browser using ctrl/cmd + U.